# Fitting a sine wave of known amplitude with two measured points approximately 1/2 period apart

Tags: trigonometry

I am designing an calibration GUI for an optical setup.  Specifically, this is a calibration for a half-wave plate rotating to attenuate a laser, where the input is the half-wave plate angle and the output is the laser power. The output function of the calibration is known to be a sine wave, and so the simplest calibration would would return four parameters:

1. The measured minimum value of the wave (minimum laser power)
2. The measured maximum value of the wave (maximum laser power)
3. The measured x,y (plate angle, laser power) coordinate near the steepest positive derivative
4. The measured x,y (plate angle, laser power) coordinate near the steepest negative derivative known to be approximately 1/2 period from point #3.

How would you derive the equation of the sine wave described by these four pieces of information?  Specifically, how would you get the phase shift and period?

Given the equation for a sine wave: $$y = a*sin(b(x+c))+d$$
where: a = amplitude, b=2π*frequency, c = phase shift, and d = yoffset

We can readily find a and d where:
$$a = \frac{(wave\ maximum - wave\ minimum)}{2}$$
$$b = wave\ minimum + a$$

The remaining variables to solve for are c and d.

To do this, I first tried isolating b:
$$y=a\ast sin\left(b\left(x+c\right)\right)+d$$
$$y\ -\ d=a\ast sin\left(b\left(x+c\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}=sin\left(b\left(x+c\right)\right)$$
$$arcsin{\left(\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}\right)}=b\left(x+c\right)$$
$$\frac{arcsin{\left(\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}\right)}}{\left(x+c\right)}=b$$

But when I plug this back in to solve for c, everything just cancels out:
$$y=a\ast sin\left(\frac{arcsin{\left(\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}\right)}}{\left(x+c\right)}\left(x+c\right)\right)+d$$
$$y=a\ast sin\left(arcsin{\left(\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}\right)}\right)+d$$
$$y=a\ast\left(\frac{y\ -\ d}{a}\right)+d$$
$$y=\ y\ -\ d+d$$
$$y=y$$
When I plot $$y=arcsin\left(sin\left(x\right)\right)$$ It becomes clear that this statement only holds true while: $$-π/2 ≤ x ≤ π/2$$  Additionally, I think I'm getting stuck by not factoring in the constraint that measurements #3 and #4 are known to be approximately one half period apart.  Therefore, I was wondering how do you solve for the phase and frequency from these measurements?

Comment: Assuming perfect measurements without noise, you have $amp=(max-min)/2$, $y_{offset}=min+amp$, $period=2(x_4-x_3)$ and $phase=(x_3\bmod period)2\pi/period$, where $x_3$ and $x_4$ are the $x$ values from measurement 3 and 4. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The catch is that points 3 and 4 aren't guaranteed to be at the midpoint, just near to it, so the period and phase need to take into consideration the effectively arbitrary nature of these points.

Comment: So you assume the $x$ and $y$ values are clean (without noise), but just not exactly at the abscissa of the steepest derivatives?

Comment: That is correct.  I just tried solving for phase shift: where 
$$
phase shift = arcsin((y-yoffset)/amplitude)/frequency-\ \theta
$$

But when I plug that back frequency also cancels out:
$$
y=\ amplitude\ast\sin\(frequency(\theta+arsin((y-yoffset)/amplitude)/frequency-\ \theta))+yoffset
$$

Comment: I just tried solving for only phase shift and again both phase shift and frequency cancel out.  I'm wondering if this is because I'm not including the a priori assumption that the two points are roughly a period/2 phase shift apart?

Comment: Yes, you will need to include this assumption. I only have access to my phone right now and will get back to you tomorrow, if the question hasn't been answered by then.

Comment: I just wanted to add an answer, but apparently the question has been closed. If you are still interested in an answer you should try and edit the question such that it meets the MSE guidelines.

Comment: That you for taking the time to come up with an answer - I have submitted a revision to the question.